# CSS Media Tag is not working on production but local although the @media is in the source .css

Tags: css

I am trying to modify an existing web into responsive by adding the line below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: @screen-768 - 1){
...}
```

It works fine in my development environment, but when it comes to production, somehow the @media line was not found during inspect in Google Chrome. Anyway when checking the source of the page the .css is updated.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

can I ask why you are using @media only screen and (max-width: @screen-768 - 1){ ...} instead of

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px){ ...}

and maybe the reason you cant see the source in google chrome inspect is because of the CSS HACK that is used by the developers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Changing the 768-1 to 767 make it work. Anyway the method was done by the previous developer and I got framed by it.

Answer (score 0):

`@media only screen and (max-width: @screen-768 - 1){...}` Is not the best way to write media queries.You can write `@media only screen and (max-width:767px){...}`

You can see a nice description and working examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)